# I want a convert python to json

Tags: python, json, parsing

I want to convert python parser to json. Here's a code of my python parser.

```
import re
import time
from urllib.parse import quote, unquote
from urllib.request import urlopen 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://fasie.ru"
page = urlopen(url)
html = page.read().decode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
div = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'wrap')
programms_list = div[1].find('ul', class_='').find_all('ul', class_='')[1]
hrefs = programms_list.find_all('a')
download_links = set()
response = requests.get(url+'/programs')
parse_text = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
links = set([x.get('href') for x in parse_text.find_all(href=re.compile('^/programs/'))])
def main():
    for h in hrefs:
        url_h = f"https://fasie.ru{h.get('href')}"
        page_h = urlopen(url_h)
        html_h = page_h.read().decode("utf-8")
        soup_h = BeautifulSoup(html_h, "html.parser")
        sections = soup_h.find_all('section')
        for s in sections:
            print(s.text)
    for link in links:
        response = requests.get(url+link)
        parse_text = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        download_links.update(set([x.get('href') for x in parse_text.find_all(href=re.compile('^/upload/docs'))]))
        for link in download_links:
            file_name = unquote(link).split('/')[-1]
            response = requests.get(url+quote(link))
            with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.content)
main()
```

And here's what json should look like

```
[
  {
    "source": "Ссылка, откуда взята информация", // в данном случае ссылка fasie.ru
    "name": "ИнноШкольник",
    "description": "Информация из вкладки `О программе`",
    "program": "Данные из вкладки `Конкурсы, программы` в формате HTML",
    "contacts": [
      {
        "name": "Имя контакта",
        "tel": "Телефон",
        "email": "Почта контакта"
      }
    ],
    "documents": [
      {
        "source": "Ссылка на файл оригинальная, т.е откуда скачали",
        "path": "Относительный путь к файлу (уже скачанного)",
        "name": "Название файла",
        "extension": "Расширение файла (напр. pdf)",
        "size": 123 // Размер в байтах
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

It should be to create a bot that will automatically output information from the python code to a JSON

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: So here's the question. What the code must be to convert python code to json?

Comment: That's not valid JSON. JSON doesn't accept comments and you have two lines with comments on them

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Thx to user510170

```
import json
import codecs
import re
import time
from urllib.parse import quote, unquote
from urllib.request import urlopen 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from sys import getdefaultencoding
import yaml
import requests
import bleach

url = "https://fasie.ru"
page = urlopen(url)
html = page.read().decode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
div = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'wrap')
programms_list = div[1].find('ul', class_='').find_all('ul', class_='')[1]
hrefs = programms_list.find_all('a')
download_links = set()
response = requests.get(url+'/programs')
parse_text = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
links = set([x.get('href') for x in parse_text.find_all(href=re.compile('^/programs/'))])
programs = []

def main():
    for h in hrefs:
        program = {}
        url_h = f"https://fasie.ru{h.get('href')}"
        page_h = urlopen(url_h)
        html_h = page_h.read().decode("utf-8")
        soup_h = BeautifulSoup(html_h, "html.parser")
        soup_b = BeautifulSoup(html_h, 'lxml')
        description = soup_h.find('section', {'id': 'content-tab3'})
        program['source'] = url_h
        program['name'] = h.text.strip()
        program['description'] = description.text.strip().replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '').replace('\r', '') if description else ''
        program['program'] = str(soup_h.find('section', {'id': 'content-tab1'}).get_text()).replace('\n', ' ').replace('\t', ' ').replace('\r', ' ')
        try:
            notag = soup_b.find('div', class_='tabs').find('section', id='content-tab5').find_all('tr') 
        except AttributeError:
            notag = soup_b.find('div', class_='tabs').find('section', id='content-tab4').find_all('p')
        for n in notag:
            nams = []
            tels = []
            emails = []
            contacts = []
            contact = {}
            try:
                nam=[i.text.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\t', ' ').replace('\r', ' ').replace(u'\xa0', u' ').replace('   ', '') for i in n.find_all('h4')]
                if nam==[]:
                    nam=[i.text.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\t', ' ').replace('\r', ' ').replace(u'\xa0', u' ').replace('   ', '') for i in n.find_all('b')]
                for i in nam:
                    if i==' ':
                        pass
                    else:
                        nams.append(i)
                email = n.find('a').text.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\t', ' ').replace('\r', ' ').replace(' ', '')
                if email=='':
                    pass
                else:
                    emails.append(email)
                tel = [i.text.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\t', ' ').replace('\r', ' ').replace(u'\xa0', u' ').replace('   ', '') for i in n.find_all('nobr')]
                for i in tel:
                    if i=='':
                        pass
                    else:
                        tels.append(i)
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        contact['namе'] = nams
        contact['email'] = emails
        contact['tel'] = tels
        contacts.append(contact)
        program['contacts'] = contacts
            

        sections = soup_h.find_all('section')
        documents = []
        for s in sections:
            download_links.update(set([x.get('href') for x in s.find_all(href=re.compile('^/upload/docs'))]))
        for link in download_links:
            file_name = unquote(link).replace('%20', '').split('/')[-1]
            response = requests.get(url+quote(link))
            with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.content)
            document = {}
            document['source'] = url+link.replace('%20', ' ')
            document['path'] = file_name
            document['name'] = file_name
            document['extension'] = file_name.split('.')[-1]
            document['size'] = len(response.content)
            documents.append(document)
        program['documents'] = documents
        programs.append(program)
    with open('output.json', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(programs, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))

main()
```

Comment: But here's an one nuance. It print only one contact in every source. I need several, depending on how many names, phone numbers, and mailboxes there are on each "#kontaktu". I tried this code: '''contact['namе'] = list(f"nams - {contact['namе']}")'''. But it didn't helps me. What I must do? What the code I must write?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood what you meant but to "json stringify" an object you can just create the object in question, import the json library and use the dump method of the json module

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).